# org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateOptimisticLockingFailureException

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

When running the `getsession.update(data)` getting below error;

> `org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateOptimisticLockingFailureException:
>   Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row
>   count: 0; expected: 1; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected
>   row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1`

Please help me resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From documentation:

> public class StaleStateException extends HibernateException
>   Thrown when a version number or timestamp check failed, indicating that the Session contained ***stale data*** (when using long transactions with versioning). Also occurs if we ***try delete or update a row that does not exist***.
>   Note that this exception often indicates that the user failed to specify the correct unsaved-value strategy for a class!

So, check:

1. Does updating entity exist in a DB?
2. Are there any modifications of the entity which may make it stale?

Comment: Hi Nikolay, Thank you for your valuable comments I have checked the entity classes, input testcase data. Here in the testcase data , the primary key data is different from that in the database so it was not updating.

Answer (score 0):

issue is occuring becouse batch update supposed to update atlest one row, but it  did not update any row. becouse your are trying to update row that row is deleted, so batch update is not updating the row and throwing exception.